# Cannot insert value NULL on UPDATE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, ssms

I have an update statement that is returning an error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PAYMENT_AMOUNT'; table Subscriptions

I understand that I need to set columns that are "not null"s that I may not be using, but are still in the table, to their default values. But I'm not sure how to write that and haven't had any luck finding examples that relate.

My fear is that by saying PAYMENT_AMOUNT = default that it will override any of the columns that have data in them. The overall point of my update statement is to update only specific columns in one table (that didn't populate accurately), with columns from another table with the correct data.

```
UPDATE S
SET S.PAID_THRU = CASE
                      WHEN S.PAID_THRU IS NULL THEN TRANS.PAID_THRU 
                      WHEN S.PRODUCT_CODE = '2019_NATL' AND S.PAID_THRU != '12/31/2019' THEN TRANS.PAID_THRU
                      WHEN S.PRODUCT_CODE = '2019_DIVISION' AND S.PAID_THRU != '12/31/2019' THEN TRANS.PAID_THRU
                      WHEN S.PRODUCT_CODE = '2019_REGION' AND S.PAID_THRU != '12/31/2019' THEN TRANS.PAID_THRU
                  END,
    S.PAYMENT_AMOUNT = CASE 
                          WHEN S.PAYMENT_AMOUNT = '0.00' THEN TRANS.AMOUNT
                       END,
    S.BALANCE = CASE 
                   WHEN S.BALANCE = '0.00' THEN (TRANS.AMOUNT - TRANS.AMOUNT) 
                END
FROM 
    name N
INNER JOIN
    trans ON n.ID = trans.BT_ID 
INNER JOIN
    SUBSCRIPTIONS S ON TRANS.BT_ID = s.ID
WHERE 
    member_type = 'C'
    AND join_date > '7/1/2018'
    AND trans.TRANSACTION_DATE > '7/1/2018'  
    AND n.paid_thru = '12/31/2019'
    AND trans.product_code = s.product_code
    AND trans.BT_ID = s.ID
```

Comment: why do you have a comma ',' after `SET`?

Comment: Are you talking about your ID field?  It is not null because you are joining on it.  Your error must be referring to some other field that you are actually trying to update, because if it cant be null, it would have never been inserted into the table in the first place.

Comment: You could add a default to each of your case statements, setting the column to itself (so nothing happens). e.g `S.PAID_THRU = CASE ... ELSE S.PAID_THRU`

Comment: Sorry @Brad, I was using that just as an example, but edited to provide the exact error and field.  Also, comma I forgot to remove.

Comment: @dustytrash that worked, thank you!  Didn't realize it was something so simple causing that error.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you have an out for your switch statement.  Could you just set the column back to its original value?

```
S.PAYMENT_AMOUNT = CASE 
  WHEN S.PAYMENT_AMOUNT = '0.00' THEN TRANS.AMOUNT
  ELSE S.PAYMENT_AMOUNT
END
```

Or another way to only narrow the update statement down to values that have a trans amount would be to null check in the WHERE clause:

```
AND NOT TRANS.AMOUNT IS NULL
```

Comment: That did the trick!  From what I had read I thought I was going to have to list out every not null field in the table and it's default, which would have been messy.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query like this :

```
UPDATE S
SET S.PAID_THRU = CASE WHEN S.PAID_THRU IS NULL or (S.PAID_THRU != n.paid_thru and S.PRODUCT_CODE in ('2019_NATL', '2019_DIVISION', '2019_REGION') then TRANS.PAID_THRU
                      else S.PAID_THRU END,
    S.PAYMENT_AMOUNT = CASE WHEN S.PAYMENT_AMOUNT = '0.00' THEN TRANS.AMOUNT ELSE S.PAYMENT_AMOUNT END,
    S.BALANCE = CASE WHEN S.BALANCE = '0.00' THEN (TRANS.AMOUNT - TRANS.AMOUNT) else S.BALANCE END

FROM name N
INNER JOIN SUBSCRIPTIONS S ON n.BT_ID = s.ID
INNER JOIN trans ON n.ID = trans.BT_ID AND trans.product_code = s.product_code AND trans.TRANSACTION_DATE > '7/1/2018'

WHERE member_type = 'C' AND join_date > '7/1/2018' AND n.paid_thru = '12/31/2019'
```